# C++ crashes when I access the next Node pointer

Tags: c++, linked-list, crash, nodes

I am creating a list container using Node.

This is how the Node structure look like; ***`mFirst`*** *is a private data member for the List class*.

```
struct Node{
    Node(const EType & d, Node *n = nullptr) : mData(d), mNext(n) { }
    EType mData;
    Node *mNext;        
};
Node *mFirst;
```

There is a function which is used to delete an element from the container.

The problem happens on line **`temp2->mNext = temp->mNext;`**.

The element is deleted but the program will crash.

I have no idea what is causing the problem.

```
template <typename EType>
void Set<EType>::remove(const EType & x) {
    if (isElement(x)) {
        Node *temp = mFirst;
        Node *temp2 = nullptr;
        while(temp->mData != x) {
            temp2 = temp;
            temp = temp->mNext;
        }   
        if (temp2 == nullptr) {
            mFirst = temp->mNext;
        } else {
            temp2->mNext = temp->mNext;
        }
    }
}
```

If I change the line to:

```
temp = temp->mNext;
temp2 = temp2->mNext;
temp2 = temp;
```

Nothing happens, and the function won't work.

Are both expressions not the same?

Comment: `the program will crash`: have you more information about that ? Your `remove` method seems correct, even if you could merge the `isElement` method within `remove` to avoid far assertions from their use. Note that you have not deleted `mFirst` or `temp2->mNext`.

Comment: try to use debugger to figure out what happens at the line in question, it should be either `temp2` or `temp` is `nullptr`, or try to print `temp2` and `temp` to a console to see which of those is `nullptr`. Then try to understand under which conditions it happens. And thus you will debug your problem.

Answer (score 0):

For every pointer that you use, you must check is it different from 0: You check only for tmp2, but you should check for tmp too.

```
while(tmp && tmp->mData !=x)
```

You need to check if the element was found in the list

```
if(tmp)
{
  if(!tmp2)
  {
    mFirst = tmp->mNext;
    delete tmp;//now it is deleted
  }
  else
  {
    tmp2->mNext = tmp->mNext;
    delete tmp;//now it is deleted
  }
```

You also need to pay attention when creating the list: the last element must have mNext set to 0.

Answer (score 0):

First of all. You're last code does nothing. Read it again.
Then you are never checking the end of your list, even in the loop.
How do you know the element has been deleted? If your program crashed at this line, nothing is deleted.
And I don't see any delete, so you're never going to delete the object,  it will still be in memory.
Can you give us the exact crash message? Using gdb maybe

Comment: The program will run then crashes. I have put a print() after I remove an element so I could see the element was gone before the program shut down. I couldn't be bothered with deleting the objects since I could not even get the program to run properly.

Comment: Then we don't know if this function is causing the crash or not.  Try using a debugger to run your code, you should get more information about the crash.